# Check if output is present on component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular9

Consider the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test'
  template: 'Hello!'
}}
export class TestComponent {
  @Output() readonly selectionChange = new EventEmitter<SomeTypeHere>();
}
```

With the call:

```
<app-test (selectedChange)="selectedChangeHandler($event)"></app-test>
```

Note that I've written `selectedChange` instead of the correct output name `selectionChange`. Angular 9 with the flag `strictTemplates` enabled didn't help me at all. It failed silently. The interesting part is that if I do the same thing for `@Input`, the app catch the error(s) and doesn't compile.

Is there any way to throw an error if I try to "listen" an inexistent `@Output`?

Comment: was there any errors with previous versions of Angular? I think it never threw any error on this

Comment: @Aravind no, it never threw errors. I'm asking if it's possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to throw error? is there a specific need? I'm trying to understand your question

Comment: @Aravind well, I'm working on an enterprise app with many developers, so it's important to have some kind of information/warning/error. Sometimes someone change/remove an `@Output()` in a shared lib, or even on the app and forget to remove the *calls*... and as we don't have compilation errors, like we have for `@Input()`, we can't find exactly what causes certain problems (or even for not keeping garbage in the code). Unit tests could be helpful? Maybe, but at the time isn't possible yet due to the time.

Answer (score 5):

There is no error thrown because the [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding) in Angular is used not only with `@Output`s and `EventEmitter`s, but also to listen to the [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) such as `click`, `keyup`, etc. It could even be used to listen to [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). For example, if you create and emit a custom event in the child component:

```
constructor (private el: ElementRef) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    const domEvent = new CustomEvent('selectedChange', { custom: true });
    this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(domEvent);
}
```

Then in the parent component you can catch it by its name:

```
<app-test (selectedChange)="selectedChangeHandler($event)"></app-test>
```

Angular uses [target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) internally (you can make sure of it looking at the links below), where `type` could be any string.

That's why it doesn't throw any exception if it doesn't find matching `@Output`s.

[listenToElementOutputs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/element.ts#L182-L197)

[DefaultDomRenderer2.listen](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L238-L248)

[EventManager.addEventListener](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.0.2/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/event_manager.ts#L38-L51)

[DomEventsPlugin.addEventListener](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/events/dom_events.ts)

Comment: Hey @Kirill Simonov thanks for your answer! Well, taking your statement: "There is no error thrown because the event binding in Angular is used not only with @Outputs and EventEmitters, but also to listen to the DOM events such as click, keyup, etc", why then if you pass an inexistent `@Input()` (remember that Inputs have the same characteristics: can be something global like `disabled`, `id`, etc.) Angular threw errors? Why it works for `@Input`, but not for `@Output`? Also, I'm trying to find a way to warn/throw error if an inexistent `@Output` is passed.

Comment: @dev_054 this is because the set of properties is limited by the existing properties of a DOM element, directive or component, so Angular can easily check whether this property exists or not. Events, on the other hand, are bound using `addEventListener` (I will add some links to my answer to show it). I think, it was done intentionally, so the developers could use event binding with their own custom events. I believe there is no way to disable this behavior at compile time. Although some IDEs (like IntelliJ Idea) may highlight such places and display warnings.

Comment: @dev_054 remember that you could also use one-way binding for [HTML attributes](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property) using `[attr.any-attribute]`, in this case no error will be thrown either.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
ngOnInit() : void {
 if(this.selectionChange.observers.length > 0){
   console.log("Nice coding");
 }else{
  console.log("Something is wrong!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution to your problem, however some cases can be covered.

1. If you have any output that is used in 100% of places like button `click` event then you can make it part of the selector i.e. `selector: 'app-test[selectionChange]'`. Also you can do this for example: `selector: 'app-test[selectionChange]', app-test[click]'` meaning `click` or `selectionChange` is required.
2. If you are refactoring code and rename output i.e. `selectionChange` to `selectedChange` then you can use this selector: `selector: 'app-test:not([selectionChange])'` to force users to update.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using VS Code you can install this extension: [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) will throw a warning when a method or property is not defined. This extension works with both, outputs and inputs (and attrs, etc...).

[image: Identifier 'XXXvalidateProvider' is not defined.]

Comment: Your sample shows an @Input. For `@Output`, Angular Language Service doesn't help in nothing. Let me know if you need me to clarify the question.

Comment: For an `@Output` you will see the same error message.